# Version mismatch issue when using LastWriteTime.Ticks

Tags: c#, .net

I had a code like this

```
dataset.DataVersion.AddDataVersionRow((new FileInfo(path + PermissionFile)).LastWriteTime.Ticks);
```

But when some changed it for getting some other functionality sometimes it is not working,i dont know
why it is not working.This is the modified ,not working code

```
long version = (new FileInfo(path + PermissionFile)).LastWriteTime.Ticks;
                if (dataset.DataVersion.Count == 0)
                {
                    dataset.DataVersion.AddDataVersionRow(version);
                }
                else if (version > dataset.DataVersion[0].Version)
                {
                    dataset.DataVersion[0].Version = version;
                }
```

Do i need to add one more else loop here

Comment: 1. `else` is no loop ;-)  
2. What do you mean by "not working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer without more information, but maybe you want to update the last entry in DataVersion:

```
int count = dataset.DataVersion.Count;
if (count == 0)
{
    dataset.DataVersion.AddDataVersionRow(version);
}
else if (version > dataset.DataVersion[count-1].Version)
{
    dataset.DataVersion[count-1].Version = version;
}
```

Comment: I did nt check in IDE,,but by seeing your code what is the difference

Comment: Great Henri,,its working but what is the logic behind that,i am wondering what is the differnece

Comment: @peter: it was just a guess. In your first code fragement, new versions were appended at the end of the list. You said this did work OK. So I assumed it would be best, to update the last entry in the list so this is still the most recent one.